# windows CMD in browser

Tags: windows, browser, cmd.exe, terminal-emulator

Basically want something that I can use in demos to access a CMD instance of a remote machine in a browser, i.e. a webserver providing some windows CMD like interface over the web.

Security is not really important (would actually use it with no security configured as it's for temporary usage on a local LAN and quick easy access is most important aspect).

Basically something like one of the following, but for Windows:

- [gotty](https://github.com/yudai/gotty)
- [termshare](https://github.com/progrium/termshare)
- [showterm](https://showterm.io/)

Note: It looks like you can do this for powershell ([link](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askpfeplat/archive/2012/09/17/want-remote-powershell-management-from-your-browser-see-how-powershell-web-access-in-windows-server-2012-may-help.aspx)), but still can't seem to find one for a plain Windows cmd interface.

Comment: what wrong with the powershell option?

Comment: nothing's really wrong with it other than my familiarity with it. I don't really use powershell and neither does anyone else at my workplace that might also want to use it for a demo in the board room. I'll probably end up using powershell though if I can't find something.

Comment: You can turn a PowerShell console to run CMD by typing `cmd`.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing I can think of is an HTML5 RDP server, like [**Thinfinity**](https://www.cybelesoft.com/thinfinity/remote-desktop/server/).

The Workstation version offers 1 free seat and the trial for the server version has a 30-day free evaluation period.

Comment: This seems to work, but I might as well then go with a normal windows RDP session. Using their live demo it also had some slowness / unresponsiveness when using CMD...was wondering if it's overhead added by RDP for something that just sends text to and fro, although might just be my connection causing the lag.

Answer (score 1):

logmein pro has a command prompt available from the web interface. 
https://secure.logmein.com/welcome/webhelp/EN/Pro/LogMeIn/t_host_compman_command.html
I'm not sure where it fits in their current pricing structure. I was never too impressed with their product though, it didn't resize well, for example.